# Infinite loop when calling $evalAsync within a $watch function (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, scope, digest

I'm following along Tero Parviainen's book "Build your own angularJS" and I'm finding trouble understanding one of the concepts he introduces when talking about $evalAsync.

In one of the examples he declares a watcher which always calls $evalAsync:

```
it('eventually halts $evalAsyncs added by watches', function() {
  scope.aValue = [1, 2, 3];
  scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {
      scope.$evalAsync(function(scope) { });
      return scope.aValue;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue, scope) { }
  );
  expect(function() { scope.$digest(); }).toThrow();
});
```

Seeing that example, I would expect the digest cycle to iterate twice through the watchers until stopping. In the implementation of the scope, the code runs until the digest is not dirty or there are no more $evalAsyncs in the queue.

```
Scope.prototype.$digest = function () {
  var ttl = 10;
  var dirty;
  this.$$lastDirtyWatch = null;
  do {
    while (this.$$asyncQueue.length) {
      var asyncTask = this.$$asyncQueue.shift();
      asyncTask.scope.$eval(asyncTask.expression);
    }
    dirty = this.$$digestOnce();
    if ((dirty || this.$$asyncQueue.length) && !(ttl--)) {
      throw '10 digest iterations reached';
    }
  } while (dirty || this.$$asyncQueue.length);
};
```

If for each iteration in the loop, one asyncTask if shifted from the array, how comes that that loop runs forever? Shouldn't the loop stop because the $$asyncQueue gets emptied?

Hope I made myself clear and thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

By calling:

```
scope.$evalAsync(function(scope) { });
```

you add new item to `asyncQueue`:

```
asyncQueue.push({scope: this, expression: expr, locals: locals});
```

So removing task by `this.$$asyncQueue.shift();` we call new iteration a.e. new digest cycle.

Anyways the proper implementation of watcher is:

```
scope.aValue = [1, 2, 3];
  scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {
      return scope.aValue;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue, scope) { }
  );
```

Comment: Hey Maxim! Thanks for your answer. So as I understand, only one digest cycle is triggered, but as you said, when calling $evalAsync, you add a new item to asyncQueue. What I don't get is why this process repeats over and over. I console.log at the start of the digest function and it's only called once. Why executing 
```
function (scope) {}
```
with $eval keeps adding one item to the $$asyncQueue?
Thanks again and sorry for the trouble in understanding

Comment: @Riboher `What I don't get is why this process repeats over and over.`  this is what I said, `scope.$evalAsync` adds new item to `asyncQueue` and calls new watch iterator. New iterator calls again `scope.$evalAsync` so this loop is infinite